# Is there an unminified version of kinetic.js?

Tags: kineticjs

Where can I find an unminified version of kinetic.js? I could not find such a version on either the github page or http://kineticjs.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un-minified or source file of KineticJS is always available on KineticJS page. Right below the download button look for a link that says **[Download source](http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.4.js)**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one answer: http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.4.js

I went to the normal kinetic.js minified download page and removed the "min" from the url.